# Descobrir página atual e mudar estilo de Div

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma `div` que se repete cinco vezes:

```
<div class="produtosMenu f-left margin-top-35 margin-bottom-35">
    <a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a>
</div>
```

É uma listagem de categorias de produtos, quero que quando eu clique na categoria referente ao produto, a cor do menu mude, para vermelho, por exemplo.

Tem como fazer isso com `Jquery`?

Comment: Pode postar seu código completo? seu html com menus e conteúdo.

Comment: Esse é o HTML amigo. Está dentro de um laço de repetição. Ou seja, essa `div` que postei acima, repete-se cinco vezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim! Há opções no jQuery como adicionar uma classe ao elemento (`.addClass()` [link](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)) ou diretamente um CSS (`.css()` [link](http://api.jquery.com/css/)).

A solução seria adicionar uma id ou class específica para cada elemento utilizado e depois configurar estes eventos com o jQuery:

```
$('#categoriacamisetas').click(function(){
   $('menucamisetas').css({"background-color":"red"});
});
```

Ou...

Criar uma classe com os estilos desejados para cada classe, p.e. `.estilocamiseta` e depois via jQuery, adicionar este estilo (via classe) ao menu quando a categoria for selecionada:

```
$('#categoriacamisetas').click(function(){
   $('menucamisetas').addClass("estilocamiseta");
});
```

Sobre descobrir qual página estou:
Podes adicionar uma variável para pegar o *path* atual: `var local = window.location.pathname;` e depois configurar os eventos através de condições. Nesta página, por exemplo, a var retorna */questions/25815/descobrir-página-atual-e-mudar-estilo-de-div*.

Espero ter acrescentado.
Abraço.

Comment: Muito obrigado! :) Ele aplicou a cor que determinei depois que eu cliquei, porém, quando a página carrega a outra listagem de produtos, referente ao menu carregado, ele fica normal, sem as aplicações. Será que devo usar um atributo?

Comment: Esse evento que citei só é ativado ao passo do clicar. Tente colocar um *handle* através de condições: se estou na página /contato, adicionar a classe ou CSS ao menu. Vou tentar reproduzir aqui.

Comment: Feito: http://jsfiddle.net/b2nT5/2/

Comment: Ficou difícil de representar pois o JSFiddle usa um *iframe*. Ao entrar, vai se deparar com um *alert* mas nada deverá acontecer. Clique no 'Run' e veja a mágica. A lógica é você pegar o *link* atual e definir condições. Se o *link* for tal, fazer o que quiser.

Comment: É claro que o script não será rodado após um *alert* em seu site. Esse é o motivo pelo qual o estilo foi adicionado após fechar este alerta: o programa só continuou rodando após o fechamento.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção. No caso seria isso? http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/85p28/

Comment: `/paginaSYS` ou `/paginaSYS/`? http://jsfiddle.net/85p28/1/

Comment: Tentei das duas formas, hehe.

Comment: Hahahaha. Depois lê a obs. que fiz no JSFiddle ;p

Comment: Ah, show de bola. O problema de eu criar um ID é que essa div está em um laço de repetição, vou tentar incrementar, para atribuir um número à ID.

Comment: Certo. Se a resposta resolveu teu problema, marque-a como resposta ;P - vou pesquisar sobre loops e atribuição de ids.

Answer (score 1):

Não vou lhe dar de mão beijada, só pensar um pouquinho, mas segue um exemplo de como fazer:

Antes:

[image: Antes]

html:

```
<header>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#tour">Tour</a>
        </li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    setNavigation();
});

function setNavigation() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    $(".nav a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:visited {
    color:#000;
}
.nav {
    padding:10px;
    border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    border-radius:5px;
    float:left;
}
.nav li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px;
}
.nav li a {
    text-align:center;
    width:55px;
    float:left;
}
.nav li.active {
    background-color:green;
}
.nav li.active a {
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

[Link no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDZNz/)

Em cada carregamento da página este script é executado e compara a href de cada link do menu com o URL da página corrente.

Note que o exemplo jsFiddle não vai funcionar porque você não pode realmente mudar a URL na janela de resultados, mas você pode facilmente copiar o código para um arquivo HTML para testá-lo.

Depois:

[image: Depois]

Answer (score 1):

Por exemplo:

```
<head>

    <style>
    .active {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    </style>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".menu").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");

});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="menu">
primeiro
</div>
<div class="menu">
segundo
</div>
<div class="menu">
terceiro
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Ana. Eu havia feito assim, o que acontece é que após o clique, há o carregamento da página.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

**Jquery**

```
var menu = window.location.toString();
$("[pagina]").each(function(index,element){
    var link = $(element).attr('pagina');

    if(menu.split(link).length>1){
        $(element).css('color','#1D1D1B');
    }

})
```

**HTML**

```
  <li pagina="paginaSYS" class="produtosMenu f-left margin-top-35 margin-bottom-35">
      <a href="/paginaSYS">tituloMenuSYS</a>
   </li>
```